# Performing a count on a table

Tags: javascript, web-applications, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I am trying to perform a count on a table being displayed on a web application. I want to find out how many rows are within the table & then from this I want to check a number that is displayed on the screen.

I'm not entirely sure how to do this, I've researched online but can't find anything to help. Would anyone be able to suggest an idea, please?

Comment: Welcome to SO! I'd suggest adding just a little more context to your question to help get better answers. The only clue on the environment you are using is one of the tags. Perhaps include some details on the tools, language, and frameworks you are using as well?

Comment: You probably have to write a Client Function http://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/obtaining-data-from-the-client/#creating-client-functions which will return number of rows in your table

Comment: I've had luck with something like const table = await something.find('.my-table); then do const rows = table.find('tbody > tr'); followed by await t.expect(rows.exists).ok() with  finally, by const count = rows.count it works.

The assertion "it exists" tends to then allow me followup with getting a count of them.  Otherwise I get a count of zero.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a regular HTML table, you can use the approach provided by Roger Studner in his comment; e.g.:

```
const table = await Selector().find('.my-table); 
const rows = table.find('tbody > tr'); 
const count = await rows.count;
```

Comment: note that .count is a property that returns a promise. if you want to use the value you probably need to await it.